# Converting ML Azure random forest to Python - what is "Number of random splits per node"?

Tags: python, random-forest, azure-ml

I want to convert a random forest model from ML Azure to Python (using `SKlearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor`. However there is a hyperparameter called "Number of random splits per node". There is no equivalent in SKlearn's random forest implementation.

Do you have any idea what it might refer to in [SKlearn's random forest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html)?

Answer (score 2):

From the **Notes** section in your link above: "The features are always randomly permuted at each split."

So using the `max_features` parameter should be analogous to "number of random splits per node".